How can you use SWTKeyboard to simulate text input (typing a backslash)
Im currently UI-testing an Eclipse-RCP application using SWTBot. At one point the user is asked to select a file for an upload where a native file dialog popup will open up. Unfortunately as of the wiki reference (wiki.eclipse.org) it is not possible to access these dialogs with SWTBot as far as i understood.
So when i was looking for a solution to upload a file anyways, i went to use the SWT-Keyboard to type the filepath in the bottom bar of my file dialog so i can get the file without having to use mouse clicks anywhere.
The problem is now that i cant simply use the keyboard.typeText(absoluteFilePath) method since apparently the keyboard does not have Keystrokes for some symbols like ':' and '\' which are crucial for file paths.
Below you can see my provisional workaround trying to fix this, but i didnt find a way to type the backslash yet as on my keyboard with german layout you need to type ALT_GR + ß where the latter is again, no valid Keystroke for the SWT-Keyboard.
  public void setSourceFile(String absoluteFilePath) {
    if (swtBot.comboBoxWithLabel("Source:").selectionIndex() == 0) {
      //opens the file dialog
      swtBot.button(" ... ").click();

      Keyboard keyboard = KeyboardFactory.getSWTKeyboard();

      // insert the path into the address bar
      for (char c : absoluteFilePath.toCharArray()) {
        switch (c) {
          case ':':
            keyboard.pressShortcut(SWT.SHIFT, '.');
            break;
          default:
            keyboard.typeCharacter(c);
            break;
        }
      }
      keyboard.pressShortcut(Keystrokes.CR);

    }
  }

Does anyone know a better way of doing this whole process of typing in a native dialog or maybe know a solution of how to type a backslash with the SWT-Keyboard?
